# Ignore softdelete for Polymorphic Relations doens't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

I have a log class having a Polymorphic Relationship to the object that where created, updated and deleted.

It's working for creating and updating but not for deleting.

When I call this for a delete log it returns `Model not found`because it is soft deleted.

```
public function loggable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function getColorAttribute()
{
    return $this->loggable->color;
}
```

So I need to ignore this softdelete for this call, but how can I do this?
The Documentation shows only the case for relationships with one to many.

Another way would be to write an own query but I wanted to ask first if it's possible to do it this way.

Comment: Could you paste your polymorphic relation definition for loggable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load soft-deleted models with **withTrashed()**:

```
public function getColorAttribute()
{
  return $this->loggable()->withTrashed()->first()->color;
}
```